# If broken code in a question is later fixed, change the title to solved or delete?

Tags: discussion

I've seen this happen a few times. Someone posts a question with a code example, then based on feedback from comments (and not answers, assume zero answers have occurred), fixes the code so that the problem no longer exists. Usually these questions get put on hold.

If the original error and fix was something that should be helpful to others, my guess is that the title be changed to solved and the question itself updated to explain what was changed that solved the problem.

If the error and fix is unlikely to be helpful to others, should the question be deleted by the author? (Again, assuming there are no answers, just comments). Eventually the question will just filter down into the past, so not a big deal, but if the community feels that deletion would be preferred, then deletion could be suggested in the comments for that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No longer repro/ typographical error" is there for large number of such questions - vote to close and let it disappear.

If you feel problem is useful enough - feel free to rollback/carefully edit solution out and post as an answer (possibly s community wiki).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've seen, but I wasn't sure if that was the recommended way to handle this. The concern was if the fix was something that would be useful to others, but that's usually not the case with these self corrected questions.

Comment: @rcgldr - I've just edited alternative while you've voted - there are rare case when question is useful by itself and you may want to edit it in proper shape.

Comment: The issue is that these self fixed question are usually already on hold by the time I see them. I haven't used the community wiki yet, I'll have to check that out.

Comment: If it is already on-hold I'd likely leave it in that state. If you feel that there is some brilliant part - at that point I would post new question with self-answer as editing code (short of roll-back) is generally frowned upon (never happened so far :) )

Comment: It's unlikely that a question put on hold would involve some brilliant fix, otherwise the hold voters would have done as you suggested. I was mostly  thinking about leaving a comment for the author of such a question for how to deal with that situation on his/her next question. If there are no answers, is there an issue with the author deleting the question?

Comment: I've seen edits to code in the review list, but most of those are formatting fixes. Some edits included changes to comments in the code (like grammar). I don't recall seeing any actual edits to the code itself.

Comment: Comment is always nice and may not be waste of time in such case as OP actually acted on comments in some way. Note that deleting (as opposed to fixing) negatively voted post will push OP close to question ban... but short of that I don't think there is any significant loss for deletion of such question. Even if OP does not delete it I believe rumba will get to it in a month and clean it from site.

Comment: @rcgldr yes - edits of actual code by anyone except OP are frowned upon/reverted/rejected. That why I said roll-back is really the only option to convert it back into question.

Comment: I'm confused, there's a "peer pressure" badge for deleting a down voted post. I thought the question ban was for deleting a post that had answers, in this case it's a post with zero answers. Should those not be deleted?

Comment: @rcgldr - you get the badge and step close to question ban... For most active users it does not matter, but for new user negative post may push over the ban limit. But really you should not consider bans when acting on the post - just decide based on content.

Comment: After browsing some posts, apparently you get a warning for possible question ban for deleting a post with answers, but don't get a warning for deleting a post without answers. Maybe this has changed since those posts were made.

Answer (score 2):

Your first assumption is incorrect.

Stack Exchange is a network of Question & Answer sites.

The user asked a question about broken code.  If the user found a solution to the broken code, they should **post an answer**!

You should never edit an answer into a question or mark a question with a "solved" title.  The way to mark a question as "solved" is by marking an answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm referring to the cases where the posters were unaware that they should have posted answers, and once the now fixed question is put on hold, they can't post an answer.

Comment: Agree with this answer - either edit in shape (proper Q/A pair) or close/vote to delete.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, if a question is put on hold, and assuming it's something that is useful to others, how do I undo this and fix this into a proper question and answer?

Comment: @rcgldr Then the answer is to rollback the question to the point when it was still a question.  If that can make it on-topic, it's time to reopen it.  If no edit makes the question on-topic, don't make any edit and the system will handle it.

Comment: @nhgrif - What level member do you have to be in order to do a rollback on a held question?

Comment: I think you only need regular editing privileges: http://i.imgur.com/MoUoiWf.png

Comment: I'd assume the same 2K as for any edit... Can't really confirm that so. You can also flag it to re-open and add good detailed comment - likely someone with enough privileges would read the comment if you don't have enough, or take to chat... The only thing you *should not* do at that point is flag for moderator attention as it clearly can be taken care of by community.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov [There is no reopen flag.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186722/288751)