# Solved but not closed

Tags: support

Please, what must be done with a question like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493011/global-variable-not-getting-set-correctly-inside-while-loop

problem (not reproducible using only the information provided in the question) has been found and solved after some comments, but question appears officially as "not answered".

Flag it "must be closed" ?

Comment: Partially related: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: I added a vote and it's "on hold" now. Somehow, that doesn't feel like progress. SE sites should permanently delete "on hold" questions that are older than, six months. There is no value in a question like this sticking around.

Comment: @Kaz - the system does delete old, closed questions that have no answers. You just don't see it.

Comment: @ChrisF What if they have answers? Those should be blown off also.

Comment: There are no some "review queue", like the one "triage", to analyze old zero answer questions?

Comment: @Kaz if they have answers then they wont normally get automatically deleted. I think if there's no upvoted answers they may be eligible for deletion. After all if there are upvoted answers there *may* be useful information.

Comment: @Kaz here are the Roomba rules: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006

Comment: And another related one http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303113/if-broken-code-in-a-question-is-later-fixed-change-the-title-to-solved-or-delet/303116#303116

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I close voted that question as off-topic with the following reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

You can flag > *Should be closed* > *Off topic* > ... same reason.

Comment: Thanks. We could also imagine a totally valid question, solved after some exchange of comments. Nobody writes an answer, thus question appears as "no answers". What to do then? (I'm a few archaeologist of questions)

Comment: If the question has value with an answer you can either ask in a comment to write an answer or write an answer yourself but make it Community Wiki and attribute the commenters.

Comment: I didn't know that community wiki answers exists. Thanks for the info, I've used it (I hope correctly) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130256/why-does-my-recv-call-block/32145360#32145360

Comment: @pasabaporaqui well, maybe ... I don't think much is lost if that question was simply close voted (maybe down voted for being unclear) and then removed by the Roomba: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion

Comment: I agree, finally I've flagged it to close candidate due to not reproducible. Another think I didn't know: Roomba.

Comment: Interesting, after edit the answer to activate the community wiki flag, previous votes still are accounted to my user reputation. I've expected they disappear from the account. Could be is too soon.

Comment: Notice that this question will not be deleted since it has score >0

Comment: @Braiam it looks like that issue is *solved* as well...